# How do I the average of data inside of a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, function, fetch, es6-promise

So I have a table populated with data from an API. Now I want to add a `<p>` tag with the average mass key from the data. Here is the code I have to get the table data which works great:
const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/';

```
  function fetchData(url) {
     return fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json());
  }


    function constructTableRow(data) {
      const row = document.createElement('tr');
      const { name, height, mass, hair_color } = data;
      row.appendChild(constructElement('td', name))
      row.appendChild(constructElement('td', height))
      row.appendChild(constructElement('td', mass))
      row.appendChild(constructElement('td', hair_color))
      return row;
   }

const swTable = document.getElementById('sw-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
fetchData(url).then(data =>
data.people.forEach(personUrl =>
    fetchData(personUrl).then(result => {
      const row = constructTableRow(result);
      swTable.appendChild(row);
   })
 )
);
```

Now here's the code I have to get the average, which doesn't work:

```
const link = 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/';
 function fetchLink(link) {
   return fetch(link).then((resp) => resp.json());
 }

 fetchLink(link).then(data =>
    data.people.forEach(personUrl =>
    fetchData(personUrl).then(result => {
      const getMass = result.mass;
         return getMass.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }) / getMass.length;
    })
  )

);
```

When I run this code I get this error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: getMass.reduce is not a function at fetchData.then.result

Can I alter this somehow to run inside of this fetch or do I have to have a separate function?

Comment: `getnMass` typo error

Comment: @nirus thanks, it still gives the same error though.

Comment: Are you sure the response data is json, if i just type the url into my browser I get a HTML page and not juste the .json

Comment: How does the `fetchData` function look like? Also, some people in your data source have `mass: "unknown"`, you probably want to filter these out.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel it parses from https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json

Comment: Thanks @helb I'll filter

Comment: @MikeL5799 See the answer, there were some problems beyond filtering (related to converting data types mainly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few unhandled problems in your code.

First, you are trying to call `.reduce` on each person's mass, which makes little sense:

```
const getMass = result.mass;
return getMass.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}) / getMass.length;
```

This is where your `getMass.reduce is not a function` error comes from – `.reduce` method works with arrays, and
`result.mass` is, for example `"77"`, so there's no `.reduce` on it.

Second, the person's mass is not a number, it's actually a string (`"77"`, not `77`), so even an array of these masses (`["87", "77", …]`) wouldn't get you the sum and average mass:

```
["87", "77"].reduce((a, sum) => a + sum) // -> "8777"
```

You have to convert these to actual numbers first:

```
["87", "77"].map(a => parseInt(a)) // -> [87, 77]
[87, 77].reduce((a, sum) => a + sum) // -> 164
```

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`, if you expect decimal masses (like `"77.25"`).

Moreover, some of these strings are not even numeric, but `"unknown"`. So you have to filter them out:

```
["87", "77", "unknown"].filter(mass => !isNaN(mass)) // -> ["87", "77"]
```

This is how i would go about it, hopefully the comments will help you with details:

```js
const getAvgMass = async url =>
  fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(
      async data =>
        (await Promise.all( // return the array after all persons are fetched and processed
          data.people.map(personUrl => // take each person's URL,
              fetch(personUrl) // fetch the data from it,
                .then(r => r.json())
                // and replace the URL in an array with person's mass
                // (parseInt parses numeral strings like "77" to 77 (integer),
                // and non-numeral strings like "unknown" to NaN):
                .then(person => parseInt(person.mass)) // => [77, 136, 49, 120, 75, 84, 77, 84, NaN, 80, 77, NaN, …]
          )
        // filter out these NaNs:
        )).filter(mass => !isNaN(mass)) // -> [77, 136, 49, 120, 75, 84, 77, 84, 80, 77, …]
    )
    // sum all masses and divide it by (filtered) array length:
    .then(masses => masses.reduce((sum, x) => sum + x) / masses.length); // -> 82.77272…


// top-level await is not (yet? https://github.com/MylesBorins/proposal-top-level-await) supported
// in browsers (except Chrome console in recent versions), so to log the result, we have to do:
// getAvgMass("https://swapi.co/api/species/1/").then(result => console.log(result)); // logs 82.77272…

// or:
// const logResult = async () => console.log(await getAvgMass("https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"));
// logResult(); // logs 82.77272…

// or even:
// (async () => {
//   console.log(await getAvgMass("https://swapi.co/api/species/1/")) // logs 82.77272…
// })();

// to use in a DOM element, just replace console.log:

(async () => {
  const avgMass = await getAvgMass("https://swapi.co/api/species/1/");
  console.log(avgMass); // logs 82.77272…
  document.getElementById("sw-mass").innerText = avgMass.toFixed(2); // sets the <span> text to 82.77
})();
```

```html
<p>average mass: <span id="sw-mass">…</span></p>
```

Comment: You can do anything you want with the result, i'll add it to the example snippet

Comment: nevermind I got it to work. I did and error thanks so much

Comment: Glad it helped. It's in the snippet anyway – basically you just wait for the result (using `async`/`await` or `.then(…`) and then do the stuff with it (log it to console or use it in an element or …).

Answer (score 1):

Each of your mass values is in a different JSON call, so you have to wait for all of the fetches to complete (using `Promise.all`) before you can calculate the average:

```js
const link = 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/';

function fetchLink(link) {
  return fetch(link).then((resp) => resp.json());
}

fetchLink(link).then(data => {
  Promise.all(data.people.map(url => { // get all the urls
    return fetchLink(url);
  })).then(responses => {
    const masses = responses.map(resp => resp.mass) // get just the mass from each
      .filter(m => {
        return m !== 'unknown' // drop the "unknown" masses from the array
      });

    const average = masses
      .map(x => x / masses.length)
      .reduce((adder, value) => (adder + value))
      .toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('sw-mass').innerHTML = average;
    return average
  });
});
```

```html
Average mass: <span id="sw-mass">(calculating)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The url 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/' returns the following but has no mass property.

```
{
"name": "Human", 
"classification": "mammal", 
"designation": "sentient", 
"average_height": "180", 
"skin_colors": "caucasian, black, asian, hispanic", 
"hair_colors": "blonde, brown, black, red", 
"eye_colors": "brown, blue, green, hazel, grey, amber", 
"average_lifespan": "120", 
"homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/9/", 
"language": "Galactic Basic", 
"people": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/4/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/5/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/6/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/7/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/9/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/10/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/11/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/12/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/14/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/18/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/19/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/21/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/22/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/25/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/26/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/28/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/29/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/32/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/34/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/43/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/51/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/60/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/61/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/62/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/66/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/67/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/68/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/69/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/74/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/81/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/84/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/85/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/86/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/people/35/"
], 
"films": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/5/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/4/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/"
], 
"created": "2014-12-10T13:52:11.567000Z", 
"edited": "2015-04-17T06:59:55.850671Z", 
"url": "https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"   }
```

The url 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json' does have the mass property but is not an array so both .reduce and .filter will not work because they are only methods that exist on array objects.

Comment: I was able to get that same url to work on a previous fetchData in the same js file. I'll edit my question to include that so you can see what I mean

Comment: check my revised question for the code that came before the one I posted.